# Find the interval of convergence of the series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty ((-1)^n+3)^n(x-1)^n$.

Tags: real-analysis, power-series

This is for my qualifying exam prep. It looks like both ratio and root tests failed because their limits do not exist. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the [root test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_test) with  $a_n=((-1)^n+3)^n$ we have $\sqrt[n]{|a_n|}=(-1)^n+3$. $\limsup_n\sqrt[n]{|a_n|}=4$. Thus the series converges for $|x-1|<\frac{1}{4}$